# HP250 does not detect headphones

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I recently acquired the HP 250 G9 laptop and installed Ubuntu 22.0.4 on it. However, I've encountered an issue where my headphones are not being automatically detected when I plug them in. To enable audio through the headphones, I have to manually select the 'headphones' option in PulseAudio, even though it still shows as 'unplugged.' Has anyone experienced a similar problem or knows how to resolve this issue?